# Force no-cache on Server Side Include?

Tags: html, apache, cgi, ssi

I have a static HTML page which includes a second HTML page, via an (Apache) `include virtual`.

The second page is also static, except that it includes the contents of an HTML `select` via an include from the server:

```
   <select id = "idListOpts" class="form-control input-md" size = 1>
     <!--#include virtual="/cgi-bin/listopts" -->
   </select>
```

This is fine, except that the `listopts` script (actually compiled C++) is dynamic, and returns content from a changing database. The problem is that I can't do anything to persuade the browser (FF 27, Chrome, Opera, IE9) that the `select` is actually dynamic. I've tried returning various `no-cache` directives in the `listopts` header, and I'm currently using:

```
   "Status: 200 OK\n"
   "Pragma: no-cache\n"
   "Cache-Control: no-cache\n"
   "Cache-Control: max-age=0\n"
   "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"
   "<option value=\"-1\">...etc"
```

As far as I can make out with Firebug, the entire HTML page, including all virtual includes, is loaded only once when the page is manually refreshed, and the `select` contents are only fetched at that time, and included as a static list. This doesn't seem to be what the Apache docs say. The [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html) say that SSIs can be used when only part of a page is to be dynamically generated.

Any idea how to fix this, short of JavaScript/Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Apache HTTPd being used, try using the [`exec` element](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_include.html#element.exec) with the `cgi` attribute set to the script. NB, it requires `mod_cgi` to be enabled, but I'm assuming this is already in place.

For example:

```
<!--#exec cgi="/cgi/listopts" -->
```

If that doesn't work, I'd debug your C++ program and check that it is guaranteed to return new data on each request. If you haven't already tried this, I'd use `strace` or an equivalent probe application to inspect the calls being made to the `listopts` program and inspect the responses it returns.

Comment: @EML does this cover your question?